# After upgrade of spring dependencies getting error A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-transactions, jta

I was using `<version.org.aspecj>1.7.4</version.org.aspecj>` and `<vesrion.org.springframework>4.0.1.RELEASE</vesrion.org.springframework>` version of my project. Recently I upgraded both of these versions to     `<version.org.aspectj>1.8.9</version.org.aspectj>` and
`<version.org.springframework>4.3.11.RELEASE</version.org.springframework>`.

I am using JPA repositories in my project, when I try to save any object I am getting the error like "A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()".

Below are my persistence.xml and other configuration. Request you to review these configurations and share your inputs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="appPersistenceUnit"
                      transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/appDS</jta-data-source>
        <!-- entities -->
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"
                      value="persistence-units/fusePersistenceUnit"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                      value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class"
                      value="jta"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="40"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
                        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" />

            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app_db"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

application-context.xml

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                     jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/appDS"/>
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory"
                     expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory"
                     jndi-name="java:comp/env/persistence/appPersistenceUnit"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>
<bean id="entityManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
<bean id="exceptionTranslator"
         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

application-tx.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>
</beans>
```

Updating error stack trace.

```
com.app.config.core.exception.CommonException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
    at com.app.config.core.exception.CommonExceptionType.getException(CommonExceptionType.java:175)
    at com.app.aspects.ExceptionConversionAspect.convertServiceException(ExceptionConversionAspect.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:611)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:66)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy318.matchIngredientToRecipe(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.web.IngredientController.matchIngredientToRecipe(IngredientController.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at com.app.aspects.ControllerExceptionConversionAspect.convertControllerException(ControllerExceptionConversionAspect.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy487.matchIngredientToRecipe(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:280)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:234)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.createModelAndView(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:96)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.handle(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:82)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.handle(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:26)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyWebHandlerTemplate.handle(ResteasyWebHandlerTemplate.java:39)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.handle(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:168)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.getTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1368)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:280)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy217.merge(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.repository.EntityJpaRepositoryImpl.merge(EntityJpaRepositoryImpl.java:890)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:358)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy309.merge(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.service.EntityJpaServiceImpl.merge(EntityJpaServiceImpl.java:191)
    at com.app.service.IngredientServiceImpl.matchIngredientToRecipe(IngredientServiceImpl.java:1622)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
    ... 87 more
```

Comment: The error message says that you are calling EntityManager.getTransaction() Do you have such code in your application.

Comment: Hi, no I am not calling EntityManager.getTransaction() explicitly. This code was working fine with 4.0.1.

Comment: @user1246979 does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634164/jta-entitymanager-cannot-use-gettransaction-spring-hibernate-entitymanage) helps..??

Comment: Ankur, I already checked that. But my concern is if I fallback to 4.0.1.RELEASE system is working fine without any issue, just change in pom.xml to 4.3.1.RELEASE and i am seeing this error. I tried with 'RESOURCE_LOCAL' didn't help.

Comment: Hey, Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10964717/7364024) help?

Comment: the transaction_type = 'RESOURCE_LOCAL' did not help? JTA does not have getTransaction under EntityManager in 4.3.1

Comment: Wich hibernate version are you using?

Comment: I am using hibernate 4.3.1.Final

Comment: Maybe you need to update it to hibernate-core 5.2.10.Final, if you check the  spring-orm that is the hibernate dependency for spring 4.3.11.RELEASE

Comment: Hi if we look at [Spring's source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/SharedEntityManagerCreator.java) their call getTransaction at line 280.

Can you add breakpoint at line 280 and watch why com.app.repository.EntityJpaRepositoryImpl.merge call getTransaction?

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of your persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="appPersistenceUnit"
                  transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/appDS</jta-data-source>
```

To this:

```
<persistence-unit name="appPersistenceUnit"
                  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/appDS</non-jta-data-source>
```

Ref:
[JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction() [Spring + Hibernate + EntityManager]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634164/jta-entitymanager-cannot-use-gettransaction-spring-hibernate-entitymanage)

Comment: What if it still want to use JTA ?

Comment: If you want to use JTA instead of JDBC local transaction, see Oscar Urbano  answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634164/jta-entitymanager-cannot-use-gettransaction-spring-hibernate-entitymanage